# Or parameterized API call crashing in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, api, nsurlrequest

I am making a call to an API where I want have `status` equal to `final` or `in progress`. Here is the call I am using:

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "https://sportspage-feeds.p.rapidapi.com/games?status=in%20progress||status=final")! as URL,
                                                cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,
                                            timeoutInterval: 10.0)
```

It works perfectly in Postman, but when trying it in my app it is crashing with this error:

`Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value: file`

Is there a different way to use `or` in Swift?

Answer (score 1):

You have manually percent encoded the space, but you have not percent encoded the two pipe characters.  As a result the initialiser for `NSURL` fails, returning `nil`.  Since you have force-unwrapped this value, your app then crashes.

You can use the function `.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters:)` to percent encode a string appropriately and then create a `URL`.

Both percent encoding a string and creating a `URL` can fail, so these operations return an optional.  You should use conditional unwrapping rather than force unwrapping to avoid crashes if these operations fail.

Many `NS` classes have bridged Swift equivalents including `URLRequest` for `NSURLRequest` and `URL` for `NSURL`.  Idiomatic Swift eschews the use of an `NS` class when a Swift equivalent exists.

Use something like

```
if let urlStr = "https://sportspage-feeds.p.rapidapi.com/games?status=in progress||status=final".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed), let url = URL(urlStr) {
    let request = URLRequest(url, timeoutInterval: 10)
    ...
}
```

As Matt pointed out in a comment, the correct way to construct a URL in iOS is to use `URLComponents`.  This allows you to specify each component of the URL independently and not worry about things like manual percent encoding.

The use of `URLComponents` is particularly important where you collect input from the user and they could attempt to manipulate the resulting URL string.

```
var components = URLComponents()
components.scheme = "https"
components.host = "sportspage-feeds.p.rapidapi.com"
components.path = "/games"
components.queryItems = [(URLQueryItem(name:"status", value:"in progress||status=final"))]

if let url = components.url {
    let request = URLRequest(url, timeoutInterval: 10)
    ...
}
```

Comment: No, should use URLComponents.

Comment: tried it but keep getting this error: ```No value associated with key CodingKeys```

Comment: That's nothing to do with the code in this question (or answer) - This is an error from your use of `Codable` for JSON decoding.  As the Magic 8 Ball says, "Ask again" - If you can't find the answer by searching for information on decoding JSON in Swift with Codable, ask a new question showing the relevant code